# Confusion about Rust modules

Tags: rust

I'm trying to create a Rust library to decode an OTF and in order to test this, I'm writing a CLI application so that I can verify its behavior from time to time.

Here are the contents of the `Cargo.toml` file.

```
# OTFDecode - A library to decode Open Type Fonts (OTF's).
[package]
name = "otfdecode"
version = "1.0.0"
edition = "2021"
```

I then have the `lib.rs` file with the following contents:

```
//! OTFDecode - A library to decode Open Type Fonts (OTF's).
mod reader;

/// Represents an Open Type Font (OTF).
pub struct OpenTypeFont {
    pub sfnt_version: u32,
    pub num_tables: u16,
}

/// Decode data as an Open Type Font (OTF).
pub fn decode(data: &[u8]) -> OpenTypeFont {
    let mut reader = reader::OpenTypeFontReader::new(data);
    let sfnt_version = reader.read_u32();
    let num_tables = reader.read_u16();

    OpenTypeFont {
        sfnt_version,
        num_tables,
    }
}
```

And I do have the `reader.rs` file:

```
//! A simple reader for reading an Open Type Font (OTF).

/// Represents a mechanism for reading an Open Type Font (OTF).
pub struct OpenTypeFontReader<'a> {
    buffer: &'a [u8],
    position: usize,
}

//# The basic implementation of the `OpenTypeFontReader` struct.
impl<'a> OpenTypeFontReader<'a> {
    //# Defines the constants which are required in this `impl` block.
    const U32_SIZE: usize = 4; // The amount of bytes in a `u32`.
    const U16_SIZE: usize = 2; // The amount of bytes in a `u16`.

    /// Creates a new OpenTypeFontReader.
    pub fn new(buffer: &'a [u8]) -> Self {
        OpenTypeFontReader {
            buffer,
            position: 0,
        }
    }

    /// Read an `u32` from the underlying buffer and increase the reader's position by 4.
    pub fn read_u32(&mut self) -> u32 {
        let bytes = self.buffer[self.position..self.position + OpenTypeFontReader::U32_SIZE]
            .try_into()
            .unwrap();

        self.position += OpenTypeFontReader::U32_SIZE;

        u32::from_be_bytes(bytes)
    }

    /// Read an `u16` from the underlying buffer and increase the reader's position by 2.
    pub fn read_u16(&mut self) -> u16 {
        let bytes = self.buffer[self.position..self.position + OpenTypeFontReader::U16_SIZE]
            .try_into()
            .unwrap();

        self.position += OpenTypeFontReader::U16_SIZE;

        u16::from_be_bytes(bytes)
    }
}
```

I then have the `main.rs` file, which is the entry point to the CLI:

```
//! OTFDecode - A CLI application to verify that the `OTFDecode` library is correctly implemented.
mod lib;

/// Represents the `main` entry point for the application.
/// This function is executed when the application is started.
fn main() {
    let data: [u8; 6] = [
        // OTF Header.
        /* - SFNT Version.     */ 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00,
        /* - Number of tables. */ 0x00, 0x19,
    ];

    let decoded_otf = lib::decode(&data);

    println!("OTF Font inspection.");
    println!("- SFNT Version: {:?}", decoded_otf.sfnt_version);
    println!("- Number of: {:?}", decoded_otf.num_tables);
}
```

NOTE: All files are at the same level (inside the `src/` folder).

Cargo is however giving me the following error:

```
error[E0583]: file not found for module `reader`
  --> src\lib.rs:26:1
   |
26 | mod reader;
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = help: to create the module `reader`, create file "src\lib\reader.rs" or "src\lib\reader\mod.rs"

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `OpenTypeFontReader` in `reader`
  --> src\lib.rs:36:30
   |
36 |     let mut reader = reader::OpenTypeFontReader::new(data);
   |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ could not find `OpenTypeFontReader` in `reader`

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0433, E0583.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0433`.
```

Why can't I use the contents of the `reader.rs` file? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: not sure but `mod lib;` don't make sense, you need to do `use otfdecode;` instead cause the lib is external to your main.rs like two different entity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cargo does not understand your usage of `lib.rs` as the entry point to your library but as a normal rust file. That's why when you declare the module `reader` in `lib.rs` cargo expects that you have a source file in a subdirectory `lib`.

You can fix the problem by changing `main.rs`:

- Remove `mod lib`
- change `let decoded_otf = lib::decode(&data);` to `let decoded_otf = otfdecode::decode(&data);`

Now cargo understands `lib.rs` correctly as the entry point to your library (because you don't have `mod lib`) and you are able to use your library as any other crate you included.

Probably this is not the best explanation, I would recommend reading the part in the book about modules.
I found [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch12-03-improving-error-handling-and-modularity.html?extracting-logic-from-main) about using code from `lib.rs` in `main.rs`

Comment: The explanation was fine - I managed to solve the issue using your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You essentially need both `main.rs` - containing the manual testing code (binary) and `lib.rs` - entry point to your library in the same project. To do this, your binary needs to treat your library as an external crate and use it with crate name:

```
use otfdecode;

// Then use otfdecode::reader::OpenTypeFont somewhere.
```